# Set dll Directory for Dllimport c#

Tags: c#, dllimport

I have a class library which i am calling an external dll. I have a web app that is calling the class library which uses the external dll method. 
The web app looks in the bin directory of the web application for the external dll.
How do i set the directory of the dll import for it to look in a folder within my web application for the dll i.e /webapp/externaldll/external.dll

Here is my code in the class library for loading the dll and calling the function.

```
[DllImport("External.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern Int32 Calink(
        string sCode,
        out int SubscriberID,
        out int MailshotID,
        out int LinkID
    );

   Int32 retvalptr = CALinkDecode(sCode, out cas,
                                           out cam, out cal);
```

Comment: see if these are helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319849/setting-dllimport-programatically-in-c-sharp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836093/how-can-i-specify-a-dllimport-path-at-runtime